# Using react form component twice on page without having them fill in at same time

Tags: forms, input, reactjs, components

Hi so I have a page with sign up and log in forms side by side. I'm using a react component for the email input section of the form. However, when filling one in, both get filled in at the same time, is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

without any code this isn't easy to answer. however it sounds like you are using a store to hold the data for your form.

try switching to let each component store its own data in state.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {val1: null, val2: null};
        this.setInputVal = this.setInputVal.bind(this);
    }
    setInputVal(e){
        this.state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(this.state);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <form>
                <input name="val1" value={this.state.val1} onChange={this.setInputVal} />
                <input name="val2" value={this.state.val2} onChange={this.setInputVal} />
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

from here let your submission update store data to do something but dont assign the value of your inputs to be what comes from the store.